# SQL Server 2008 Installation on Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: sql-server, installation

Can I install SQL Server 2008 Installation on Windows 7 Home Premium, with installing .NET framework 3.5 first? or any other issue installing on Windows 7 Home Premium.

I have already installed Visual studio 2010 Premium successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try it on my laptop (SQL Server 2008 Express on Windows 7 Home Premium x64, Core i5, 4 GB RAM), worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any reason why you can't. (Unless you run out of memory :P)